# Natural linear isomorphism of $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ to its dual

Tags: linear-algebra

For $S \in \text{Hom}(V,V)$, we have $f_S : \text{Hom}(V,V) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ defined by $T \mapsto \text{tr}(S \circ T)$ where $\text{tr}$ is the trace of the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis (which I've already shown to be well-defined, independent of the choice of basis). I've already shown that $f_S$ is a functional on $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ but I'm stuck on showing that $S \mapsto f_S$ defines a linear isomorphism of $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ to its dual (that is independent of the choice of basis, i.e. it's a natural isomorphism).

Clearly for $V_1,V_2 \in \text{Hom}(V,V)$, we have $f_S(V_1 + V_2) = f_S(V_1) + f_S(V_2)$ implied from the fact that $f_S$ is a functional on $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ but I'm stuck with showing that this map is a bijection from $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ to its dual - any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an isomorphism if and only if it's injective (or surjective), because the two spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: @egreg Ah yes. So, to show it is injective, I can just show that the kernel of $f_s$ can only contain the zero-map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that $V$ is finite dimensional, you know that $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ and its dual have the same dimension.

Therefore, in order to show that $S\mapsto f_S$ is an isomorphism, it's sufficient to show that it's injective. That is, if $f_S$ is zero, then $S=0$.

Now $f_S=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(S\circ T)=0$ for all $T$. Then …

Comment: It implies that $S=0$. For if that wasn't the case we'd have a non-zero matrix wrt to some basis of $S$, then we could find a $T$ such that the product of the matrix of $S$ with the matrix of $T$ gives a non-zero trace.

Comment: @Noble. Yes, right. Using bases doesn't mean the isomorphism depends on bases. The color of the cat is unimportant, so long as it catches mice, said one. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah, at the beginning of the question it asked to show that trace is independent of the choice of basis, which clearly carries on through to the isomorphism in showing that it is independent of the choice of basis.